# XJC with JDK 20

Tags: java-8

Is there any updates about XJC for JDK after 8 I searched a lot on google and also in the main websites there is no update after jdk 8 about it it's still not working and now we are in jdk 20 but there is no update about it

any updates

xjc updates and alternatives if any

Comment: XJC is part of API called JAXB (Java API for XML Binding) which is being maintained by Eclipse. Have a look at https://jakarta.ee/specifications/xml-binding/

Comment: nothing clear in it only show's the versions

Comment: Depending on the version that you choose, you can go through the detailed user guide. https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jaxb-ri/ https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jaxb-ri/3.0.0/docs/ch03.html